# How to make sure date entered in mm/dd/yyyy format is valid on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add a data validation formula on Google Sheets to make sure that the date being entered in mm/dd/yyyy format is valid.

Essentially, I want to make sure that mm can have values only from 01-12, dd can have values only from 01-31, and yyyy can have values only from say 2010-2050

I dont know what formula to use for the same. Essentially, I'm not sure how to access the individual parts (mm, dd,yyyy) of the string being entered so that I may enter conditions for them.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the `Data validation` option in the menus (`Data` in the menu bar at the top -> `Data validation`).

It includes an option to check if an input is a valid date, and either show a warning to the user but accept the input anyway, or show a warning and reject the input.

You can see it in action [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYzDYyF0MKJ0J2YOfyB13z59AdBm3HWvCkmYyXCMii8/edit?usp=sharing).